How to build a reverse greenhouse?
So basically, I stumbled across this concept of radiative cooling. There are a couple of YouTubers who posted videos on this topic.
What I understood, was that in passive daylight radiative cooling, one applies some kind of coating or film with high sunlight reflectance and high longwave infrared emissivity.
Now, there was also one video which talked about an „inverse greenhouse“. Instead of having glass which is transparent to sunlight but blocks infrared, you have a material that blocks sunlight, but is transparent to infrared.
This however sounds different then the first method.
I don‘t care about any large scale application for buildings yet. And I‘ve seen a company already doing that anyway. So I‘m asking for, is more a proof of concept. Ignoring conduction, how would you build a box that would have a net cooling effect. It would behave the opposite to a greenhouse.
